# How to create VSTS Work Items from custom build task?

Tags: typescript, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I need to create VSTS work items from a custom build task in VSTS extension, Is there an API wrapper for this provided by Microsoft? What should be the best approach for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to use the TFS REST API? https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [VSTS Node API](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api) in your typescript to achieve the feature you want. The method you need will be [createWorkItem()](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api/blob/master/api/WorkItemTrackingApi.ts#L69).

Answer (score 0):

For now, there is no this build-in feature or build task in TFS.

However, using the TFS REST API just as ds19 suggest in a *powershell script* will do the trick. You may don't have to create your owner extension.

REST API: [Create a work item](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item)

```
PATCH https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${workItemTypeName}?api-version={version}
```

Below is a sample code:

```
Try

{



$WorkItemAssociatedURL = $collectionURL + $project + “/_apis/build/builds/” + $BuildId + “/workitems?api-version=2.0”

$ResponseJSON = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $WorkItemAssociatedURL -ContentType “application/json” -headers $headers -Method GET



$CountWorkitems = $ResponseJSON.count

$WorkitemUrlArray = $ResponseJSON.value



for($i = 0; $i -lt $CountWorkitems ; $i++)

{

$body =

‘[

{

“op”: “add”,

“path”: “/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild”,

“value”:’ + $BuildNumber +’

}

]’



$WorkitemUpdateURL = $WorkitemUrlArray[$i].url + “?api-version=1.0”



Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $WorkitemUpdateURL -Body $body -ContentType “application/json-patch+json” -headers $headers -Method Patch

}

}



Catch

{

Write-Host “No work item associated with this build. Kindly check the changesets”

}
```

More detail steps and info you can refer this blog [Build association with work Items in vNext](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/05/09/build-association-with-work-items-in-vnext/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Patrick, My extension is already developed using typescript. It use an external services to retrieve some data and I need to create work items for received data. I found following example, but it uses the VSS SDK which runs in client side.

[Example](https://nocture.dk/2016/01/02/lets-make-a-visual-studio-team-services-extension/)